# Is it possible to adapt the size of the handle in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have a `PolyLineROI` object from `pyqtgraph` but it is very hard to hit the handles with the mouse.
Is it possible to adjust the size of the ROI's handles to make it easier to use them?

## Update:

As proposed in the answer of musicamente I tried to subclass `PolyLineROI` which works fine concerning bigger handles but crashes when adding new handles by clicking in the plot.

Minimal Example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg


class BigHandlesPolyLine(pg.PolyLineROI):
    """Subclass of pyqtgraph.PolyLineROI, overriding addHandle with a bigger handle size"""
    def addHandle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.handleSize = 20
        super(BigHandlesPolyLine, self).addHandle(*args, **kwargs)


app = pg.mkQApp()  # create app instance

# create default values
xn = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 20, dtype=float)
yn = np.sinc(xn)
data = zip(xn, yn)

# polyline = pg.PolyLineROI(data)  # works fine
polyline = BigHandlesPolyLine(data)  # crashes when adding handles manually while executing

pg.plot().addItem(polyline)  # add polyline to a plot

exit(app.exec())  # execute app
```

Answer (score 2):

The handle size is set in the `__init__` of any ROI subclass, but you could subclass PolyLineROI, overwrite its `addHandle` method, set your handle size there, and then call the base implementation.

```
class BigHandlesPolyLine(pg.PolyLineROI):
    def addHandle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.handleSize = 10
        super(BigHandlesPolyLine, self).addHandle(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you very much! I'm wondering why this is not editable directly. This should be a issue to everyone using it.

Comment: Okay, unfortunately it crahses now when I try to add a new handly by clicking on the plot and I'm not really getting my head around why.

Comment: @Meredith I suggest you to update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), even including my answer.